# How to change pagerview index on button click?

Tags: react-native

```
const NewLogin = ({ navigation }) => {
        return(
           <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <PagerView style={styles.viewPager} initialPage={0} >
      <View key="1" >
     
     <LoginScreen navigation={navigation} />

      </View>
      <View key="2">
       <UserSignup navigation={navigation} />
      </View>
    </PagerView>  
    <View style={styles.bottomView}>
     <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
         <TouchableOpacity style={styles.existingUser} >
              <Text style={{ alignSelf: 'center',
                            color: '#ffffff',
                            fontSize: 16,
                            fontWeight: '600',
                            paddingTop: 10,
                            paddingBottom: 10 }}>Existing User</Text>
         </TouchableOpacity>
     </View>
     <View style={{borderLeftWidth: 1,borderLeftColor: 'white'}}/>
<View style={{ flex: 1}}>
         <TouchableOpacity style={styles.newUser} onPress={() =>navigation.navigate('ForgotPassword')}>
              <Text style={{ alignSelf: 'center',
                            color: '#ffffff',
                            fontSize: 16,
                            fontWeight: '600',
                            paddingTop: 10,
                            paddingBottom: 10 }}>New User</Text>
         </TouchableOpacity>
     </View>  
 </View>
      </View>
        );   
}
```

I have implemented the above code for pagerview but I am not able to change pagerview index when newuser and existing user buttons clicked. I am new to React Native and don't know to change pagerview index. What I want to achieve is when newuser is clicked I want to go to the usersignup page; similarly when existing user is clicked I want to go to the loginscreen.

Answer (score 0):

I see you use React Navigation. You can add the screens in you Navigator(Stack/Drawer/Tab) and call the screens using navigation, example:

```
<TochableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('DetailsScreen')}>
   <Text> Go to Details Screen </Text> 
</TouchableOpacity>
```

But for it work, you need add the screens and name in your navigator screen, example:

```
<NavigationContainer>
  <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="HomeScreen">
    <Stack.Screen name="HomeScreen" component={HomeScreen} />
    <Stack.Screen name="DetailsScreen" component={DetailsScreen} />
  </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

You need to read [this page](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating) of the React Navigation docs, and you can see this my example in Snack, [click here](https://snack.expo.dev/@duduzera1997/hello-react-navigation-%7C-react-navigation).

Comment: Thank you for your response but your answer is not helped me i think you understood the question wrong. navigation is working but the output which i need is i just want to change the index of pagerview not navigating to the page